# Changing widget grid size on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to change the grid size of a wordpress widget. It currently has a grid size of medium-8 and would like to change medium-6. Its on the home page of the site and has a class of home-middle-left. I'll attach a picture of the markup from the chrome console. If you need any other details, let me know. I can't think of anything else to add. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

[Html Markup of widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cvAk.jpg)

Comment: Which wordpress theme you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the HTML?

If you changed it to `medium-6`, the row won't span full width because the right column is still `medium-4`.

You could use CSS.

```
.home-middle-left {
    @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        width: 50% !important;

    }
}
```

You will need to wrap that in a medium query though, but this depends on your website settings so I cannot add this. But it will be something like the above.

Comment: I ended up finding the solution. If you go to Appearance -> Editor and then on the top right of the page you'll see "Select theme to edit" with a dropdown. Just select the theme you wish to customize. Then click on Theme Functions. This has all the html for the theme, just locate the class you want to change and go ahead and do your changes. Thanks for the help anyways